# java RMI - multiple hosts register an object with the same name

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, networking, rmi

Can I register objects with the same name coming from different machines? 
For example: Suppose we have a class X that implements a Remote interface. Then we have a class Server that takes a new  X object and registers that object with name "Name" on the rmiregistry. Then We have another machine that have the same classes and do the same thing.We can have more than one machine that runs as servers. in this configuration all the machines register their object X from different IPs, but all the objects are register with the same name. It is this possible? Is there any problem if one client call lookup with different ip and the same object name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The situation you describe is more or less impossible. Every server must in practice have its own RMI Registry so no ambiguity can arise. If you could find a way to register objects from different servers in the same Registry (and there is one, but it's very little known or used), obviously they must all use different bind-names.

Comment: can you give a reference to some source of information about this case that you told(different servers the same registry)?

Comment: It's quite simple. The RMI Registry won't accept a bind/rebind/unbind except from the localhost. However the object it is binding/unbinding doesn't have to be on the localhost. So if you have an RMI Registry, a client program on the same host that can look up other hosts can bind each lookup result into its own Registry. The other clients only need to look in that Registry: in fact they don't need to know where the actual remote objects are at all. Each host exporting remote objects still needs a Registry: the extra Registry and the binding-client are a thin extra layer on top.

Comment: OK,I believe I understand the point. My project is basically a communication between peers(so i have a server and possibly a client in every machine). My first idea was that every peer to start its own RMI Registry and bind there an object(with the same name for simplicity),but someone told me that is a good idea to have only one RMI Registry. As I see right now this is not possible . As you told me I need a Rmi Registry for every machine and another one central.

Comment: That is correct. You were misinformed. However if you have an LDAP server available you can use that instead of the RMI Registry, via JDNI, and you only need one.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the servers have their separate RMI registry, they can bind with the same name. If they share the same RMI registry, it is not possible to bind the object with the same name